# Вызов функции. so библиотеки на с#

Tags: c#, android, linux, windows

Появилась нужда использовать so библиотеку от андроид приложения, в приложение с# подскажите реально ли это под виндовс или лучше делать под Linux с моно? И если под виндовс можно сделать, чтобы so библиотека работала, то на каком языке программирования это сделать можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET в наши дни кроссплатформенный, вы можете собрать C# приложение под Linux и использовать .so библиотеки точно так же как вы используете dll под Windows. Но запустить .so библиотеку под Windows не получится, потому что она зависит от Linux ядра, которого нет в Windows.

Для андройда в Windows есть эмулятор, если собрать приложение под Android, можно запусть его с нужной вам библиотекой.

Comment: Ну, под 10 есть WSL, там и можно запустить. Но да, под самой виндой использовать so не выйдет.

Comment: @John WSL это тоже по сути эмулятор.

Comment: А под линукс so будет работать?

Comment: @aepot а могу ли я сделать ASP NET приложение в линукс и загрузить его на сервер и чтобы нужные мне функции выполнялись на сервере и пользователи им пользовались. Суть в том что это приложение должно использоваться с сервера и обрабатывать данные в многопотоке и это должно работать с so библиотекой.

Comment: @xellan ASP.NET нет, ASP.NET Core можете. Но почему бы вам просто не почитать документацию и гайды по ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @aepot спасибо почитаю об этом, тогда если использовать ASP.NET CORЕ если я понимаю верно, то мне нет необходимости устанавливать линукс и писать в ней, я могу сделать это из под виндовс в visual studio?

Comment: @xellan верно. Если ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его, поставив зеленую галочку слева.

Comment: @aepot спасибо за ответы, про галочку слева, нажимаю и пишет что репутации мало и это не отобразится.

Comment: @xellan я таки все еще жду галочку, она чуть ниже находится. А вы пытались жать стрелочку для голосования.

Comment: @aepot поставил =) с телефона ее не было почему то, с пк есть)